# Get the maximum characters in html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know how could a normal html element with a specific width and height can handle characters in javascript like this:

```
<div id="text-habdler-with-width-and-height" ></div>
<script>
$("element").getMaxChar()
</script>
```

Comment: Characters have different widths - so this isn't possible unless you use a monospace font. In that case you need to know the width and height of a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in method in JavaScript or jQuery to get the maximum number of characters that can fit into an HTML element with a specific width and height. However, you can calculate this value using JavaScript.

```
<div id="text-handler-with-width-and-height" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2;"></div>
<script>
  function getMaxChar() {
    var element = document.getElementById('text-handler-with-width-and-height');
    var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.';
    var dummy = document.createElement('div');
    dummy.style.display = 'inline-block';
    dummy.style.font = window.getComputedStyle(element).font;
    dummy.style.lineHeight = window.getComputedStyle(element).lineHeight;
    dummy.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    dummy.textContent = text;
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    var charWidth = dummy.offsetWidth / text.length;
    var maxCharsPerLine = Math.floor(element.offsetWidth / charWidth);
    var lineHeight = dummy.offsetHeight;
    var maxLines = Math.floor(element.offsetHeight / lineHeight);
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
    return maxCharsPerLine * maxLines;
  }
  console.log(getMaxChar()); // output: 133
</script>
```

Comment: What is this actually giving us? The maximum number of i characters or the maximum number of M characters or .... It seems to just use a random piece of text. Try it with say the same piece of text doubled - you get a completely different result.